# Graphviz - how to space out the ports

Tags: graphviz

With many edges on a node, the 'ports' *(the place where an edge connect with a node)* are clustered too close together and are overlapping.

There is space to spread the ports out. Is there a way to 'justify' the spacing out of the ports?

[image: clustered_ports]

I have [read the docs](https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/portPos/) but not found anything. I was hoping to either increase the number of ports, or find another solution. I already increased the margin to increase the node size and give more space for the edges:

```
B [label=B margin=1.6]
```

---

Example code:

```
digraph {
    B [label=B margin=1.6]
    C [label=C margin=1.6]
    D [label=D margin=1.6]
    F [label=F margin=1.6]
    G [label=G margin=1.6]
    H [label=H margin=1.6]
    J [label=J margin=1.6]
    K [label=K margin=1.6]
    L [label=L margin=1.6]
    M [label=M margin=1.6]
    N [label=N margin=1.6]
    P [label=P margin=1.6]
    Q [label=Q margin=1.6]
    R [label=R margin=1.6]
    S [label=S margin=1.6]
    T [label=T margin=1.6]
    V [label=V margin=1.6]
    W [label=W margin=1.6]
    X [label=X margin=1.6]
    Y [label=Y margin=1.6]
    Z [label=Z margin=1.6]
    B -> C [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    B -> D [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> B [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    G -> B [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    B -> H [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> B [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    B -> K [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    L -> B [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> B [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    B -> N [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    P -> B [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    B -> Q [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    B -> R [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    S -> B [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    B -> T [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    B -> V [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    B -> W [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    B -> X [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    B -> Y [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    B -> Z [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    C -> B [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> C [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> C [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    C -> G [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    H -> C [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    C -> J [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    C -> K [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    C -> L [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> C [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    N -> C [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    P -> C [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Q -> C [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> C [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    C -> S [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    T -> C [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    C -> V [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    C -> W [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    X -> C [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Y -> C [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    C -> Z [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    D -> B [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> C [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    D -> F [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    D -> G [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> H [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> D [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    K -> D [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    D -> L [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    D -> M [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> N [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> P [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    D -> Q [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> D [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    S -> D [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> T [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> D [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    W -> D [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> X [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Y -> D [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> Z [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> B [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    C -> F [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> D [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    G -> F [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> H [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> F [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    K -> F [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> L [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> M [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> N [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    P -> F [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> Q [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> R [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> S [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    T -> F [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    V -> F [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    W -> F [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> X [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Y -> F [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Z -> F [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    G -> B [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    C -> G [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    G -> D [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> G [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    H -> G [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    G -> J [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    G -> K [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    G -> L [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    G -> M [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    G -> N [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    G -> P [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Q -> G [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    R -> G [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    G -> S [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    G -> T [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> G [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    W -> G [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    G -> X [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Y -> G [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    G -> Z [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    B -> H [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    C -> H [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    D -> H [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> H [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    G -> H [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    J -> H [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    K -> H [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    L -> H [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    H -> M [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    H -> N [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    P -> H [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    H -> Q [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> H [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    S -> H [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    T -> H [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> H [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    W -> H [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> H [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    H -> Y [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    H -> Z [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    J -> B [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    J -> C [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> J [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    J -> F [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    J -> G [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    J -> H [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> K [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    L -> J [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    J -> M [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    N -> J [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    P -> J [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    J -> Q [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> R [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    S -> J [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    J -> T [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> J [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    W -> J [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> X [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Y -> J [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> Z [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    B -> K [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    C -> K [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    K -> D [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    F -> K [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    K -> G [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    K -> H [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    K -> J [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    L -> K [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    M -> K [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    K -> N [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    P -> K [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Q -> K [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> K [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    K -> S [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    K -> T [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    K -> V [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    W -> K [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> K [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    K -> Y [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    K -> Z [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    L -> B [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    C -> L [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> L [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    F -> L [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    G -> L [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    H -> L [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> L [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    K -> L [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    M -> L [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    N -> L [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    L -> P [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Q -> L [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    L -> R [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    L -> S [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    L -> T [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    L -> V [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    L -> W [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    L -> X [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    L -> Y [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> L [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> B [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> C [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> D [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    F -> M [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    M -> G [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> H [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> M [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> K [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    M -> L [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    N -> M [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    P -> M [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Q -> M [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> M [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    M -> S [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> T [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> M [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    W -> M [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> M [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> Y [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> Z [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    N -> B [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    C -> N [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    N -> D [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    F -> N [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    N -> G [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    H -> N [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    N -> J [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    N -> K [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    L -> N [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> N [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    P -> N [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Q -> N [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> N [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    S -> N [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    N -> T [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    N -> V [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    W -> N [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> N [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    N -> Y [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> N [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    B -> P [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    C -> P [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> P [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    F -> P [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    P -> G [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    H -> P [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    P -> J [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    K -> P [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    P -> L [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    P -> M [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    N -> P [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    P -> Q [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    R -> P [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    S -> P [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    P -> T [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    P -> V [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    W -> P [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> P [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Y -> P [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> P [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    B -> Q [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Q -> C [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    D -> Q [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Q -> F [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    G -> Q [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Q -> H [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> Q [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Q -> K [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Q -> L [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Q -> M [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    N -> Q [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    P -> Q [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Q -> R [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Q -> S [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    T -> Q [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> Q [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    W -> Q [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    X -> Q [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Q -> Y [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> Q [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    B -> R [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    C -> R [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> D [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> F [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    G -> R [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    R -> H [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> R [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> K [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> L [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> R [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    N -> R [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    P -> R [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    R -> Q [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> S [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    R -> T [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    R -> V [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    W -> R [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    X -> R [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> Y [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> Z [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    S -> B [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    C -> S [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> S [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    S -> F [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    S -> G [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    H -> S [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    S -> J [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    S -> K [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    S -> L [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    M -> S [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    S -> N [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    P -> S [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    S -> Q [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    S -> R [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    T -> S [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    S -> V [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    S -> W [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    X -> S [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    S -> Y [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> S [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    B -> T [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    C -> T [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    T -> D [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    T -> F [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    T -> G [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    H -> T [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    T -> J [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    K -> T [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    T -> L [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    T -> M [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    N -> T [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    P -> T [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    T -> Q [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> T [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    T -> S [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> T [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    W -> T [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    T -> X [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Y -> T [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> T [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> B [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> C [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> D [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> F [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    G -> V [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> H [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> V [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    K -> V [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    V -> L [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> V [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    N -> V [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    P -> V [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Q -> V [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> R [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    V -> S [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    V -> T [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    W -> V [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    V -> X [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    V -> Y [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> V [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    W -> B [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    C -> W [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    D -> W [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    F -> W [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    W -> G [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    H -> W [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    W -> J [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    W -> K [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    W -> L [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    M -> W [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    N -> W [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    W -> P [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Q -> W [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> W [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    W -> S [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    T -> W [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    W -> V [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    W -> X [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Y -> W [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    W -> Z [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> B [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    C -> X [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    X -> D [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> F [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> G [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    H -> X [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    J -> X [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    K -> X [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> L [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> X [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    X -> N [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    X -> P [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Q -> X [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> X [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> S [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> T [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> V [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> W [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Y -> X [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> Z [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Y -> B [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Y -> C [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    D -> Y [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    F -> Y [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Y -> G [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Y -> H [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Y -> J [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Y -> K [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    L -> Y [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> Y [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    N -> Y [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Y -> P [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Q -> Y [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    R -> Y [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    S -> Y [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    T -> Y [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Y -> V [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    W -> Y [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    X -> Y [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Y -> Z [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Z -> B [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    C -> Z [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    D -> Z [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> F [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    G -> Z [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    H -> Z [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> J [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> K [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> L [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    M -> Z [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> N [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    P -> Z [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Q -> Z [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    R -> Z [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    S -> Z [arrowhead=invdot arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    T -> Z [arrowhead=invodot arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> V [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=dot dir=both]
    Z -> W [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Z -> X [arrowhead=empty arrowtail=odot dir=both]
    Y -> Z [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]
}
```

Comment: Please give an example of your code that shows the problem, preferably just the `dot` code (looks like you now use some other language to call `dot`).

Comment: Please show code inside question and the result from the pdf as an image inside the question (so all is persistent).

Answer (score 0):

Graphviz defines 8 port locations on a node, based on points on a compass (n,s,e,w,ne,se,sw,nw) (https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/portPos/).  This helps, but your nodes seem to "need" more than 8 positions.

- e.g. `B:ne -> D [arrowhead=normal arrowtail=odot dir=both]`

Maybe you could try a mixture of explicit ports and implicit ports